# Store Tags and their Values of XML File in Two Different Arrays Using Shell Script

Tags: xml, shell, xslt

I have an XML file of the format:

```
<classes>

 <subject>
  <name>Operating System</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Theory</type>
  <faculty>Prof. XYZ</faculty> 
 </subject>

 <subject>
  <name>Web Development</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Lab</type>
 </subject>

</classes>
```

Expected Output:

```
index 0 : name- Operating System
index 1 : credit- 3
index 2 : type- Theory
index 3 : faculty- Prof. XYZ
index 4 : name- Web Development
index 5 : credit- 3
index 6 : type- Lab
```

With the help of `.xsl` file, I'm able to generate an array of all tag names.

Command is: `tagArr=($( xsltproc tag_name.xsl file.xml ))`

`tag_name.xsl` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/classes/subject/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /><xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In a similar way, I want to generate another array which will have elements as the values of these captured tags.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '- ', .)"/>
```

instead of `<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />`.

As far as I understand any space is seen by the shell as a separator of array items so if you want to pass a value from XSLT to the shell as a single array item it would need to have spaces removed or replaced e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '-', translate(., ' ', '+'))"/>
```

would replace any space in an element value by a `+` symbol and then the shell would at least only have as many array items as there are elements processed by the XSLT template.

Comment: Is it possible to generate two different arrays? And, I tried using your command, it's generating some absurd type of array output. Like, when I checked the second element of array, it's returning me ` 'Systemcredit-' `

Comment: I am afraid I don't know about the conversion from XSLT output to a "shell" array, your posted XSLT creates text output with lines of element names, my adaption creates text output with lines of the concatenation of the element name, the text `- ` and the element's string value. So in terms of XSLT the output is kind of the same, text with several lines. How your shell converts that into an array I don't know, perhaps you need to quote some values if there are non-letters in a text line. As for creating two "arrays", if you run two separate XSLTs that should work I guess.

Comment: How to get the tag values of this xml file using xsl?

Comment: If you want the element's string value alone then instead of `<xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '- ', .)"/>` use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.

Comment: Getting messed up results in an array. I'll look more how can I get the values in 'Shell' array. Do let me know if you find any.

Comment: @SumeetPorwal, consider to redit the tags of your question, it seems someone removed the shell tag so experts on that topic are not likely to see your question anymore. It might help if you also mention which shell exactly you use.

Comment: I noticed it just now. I have added shell tag now. Thanks.